# Get binary data from sql server using Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

For example I have query:

```
select data from dbo.SYSFile where FileKey = 156
```

> data VarBinary(MAX)

contains JPEG images. Is there any way to quickly using SQL Enterprise Manager save data from specific record into binary file?

Comment: Enterprise Mgr?  That's so SQL 2000.  It's called Management Studio now. ;-)

Comment: Ok, ok :) Management Studio :)

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly from Mgmt Studio.  How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454919/whats-the-easiest-way-to-preview-data-from-an-image-column