# How to preview image in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using `sql server 2012`, In one of the table's column I have `varbinary(max)` values. This column is used to hold `binary values of an Image`
, where all the `images` are resides of my application. Now I want to opent that `image in sql server itself`, similary 
 when we write `select empid from employee` it is displaying empid, so is there any similary way to preview image in sql server?
 also any way to `doc/docx files` to preview in `sql server`?

Comment: It may helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454919/what-s-the-easiest-way-to-preview-data-from-an-image-column

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not have any way of displaying data in VARBINARY columns as images. You need a different tool for this that extracts the VARBINARY data and interprets it in the correct image format.

Comment: is it possible to view doc or docx file in sql server?

Comment: The only way I see would be to use SSMS add-ins as suggested by @Vladimir in another answer...

Answer (score 1):

There is a SSMS add-in called SSMSBoost that has the feature [SSMS Results Grid Visualizers](http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-results-grid-visualizers-feature).

You can get fully-functional free community license or buy the professional version. Currently both versions have the same set of features.