# Reading Images, Pdf from SQL Database via LINQPad

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, attachment, linqpad

I have a table in a database that contains all kind of attachments, images, pdf, excel, and other formats. creating an application is not an option, so I googled other options and I found [this  related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454919/what-s-the-easiest-way-to-preview-data-from-an-image-column) that mentioned LINQPad I downloaded it but I still do not know how exactly it works. Anyone please explain that to me? I can query the attachments using sql query but not sure how to dump them and preview them via the mentioned tools.

Comment: have you read the about page? https://www.linqpad.net/#db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from Dan's answer, once you have the data context set up you can dump the images from the database. I use this snippet for checking an image I've written to the database, you should be able to edit as required to match your scenario:-

```
var ii = ItemImages.Where (v => v.Id == 10).FirstOrDefault();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(ii.Image.ToArray()))
{
    System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms).Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Util.Image` built in utility for images.

Ex:

```
var personPictures = PictureTable.Take(1);
Util.Image(personPictures.First().Picture).Dump();
```

Util.Image takes a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database of your choice, most likely you'll need a data context driver
http://www.linqpad.net/richclient/datacontextdrivers.aspx

Once you establish a connection you can start writing queries against the data